# create an Azure ManagementGroup

Tags: python, azure

I am trying to use automation for the creation of Management groups. I will be using Python SDK, but I am having hard time understanding how we authenticate to Azure and generate some of these values.

I see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-managementgroups/azure.mgmt.managementgroups.operations.managementgroupsoperations?view=azure-python) shows how to create a group, but I can't find how to get the client value and then how to generate the credentials for this class. If there is a sample would be much appreciated

Comment: Any more questions? Or if it's helpful you can accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

[this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/azure/python-sdk-azure-authenticate?view=azure-python) shows how to authenticate against Azure using the Python SDK.

Comment: Thanks I had that but I don't know how the MangementGroup Class uses the credentials generated to create the ManagementGroup object. In my research I found only using MagnageGroupGraphAPI takes credentials. here; my thoughts
1-from azure.mgmt.managementgroups.operations import management_groups_operations
2- authenticate using Serviceprincipal
3- create MG object 
4- mg.create_or_update(mg1)

stuck at step 3

Comment: Start with this class https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-managementgroups/azure.mgmt.managementgroups.managementgroupsapi?view=azure-python and the link Johan pointed. Then, look for the attributes to get your ManagementGroupOperation instance

Answer (score 0):

The way to authenticate to Azure, I suggest the [Service Principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/azure/python-sdk-azure-authenticate?view=azure-python#mgmt-auth-token) and it's easy to use.

And to create the Management groups, it's a little complex what you think. The Management groups are also the managed resources. So you just need to use the `ResourceManagementClient` in Python SDK `azure.mgmt.resource`, and the class `ResourceGroupsOperations`, the whole code here:

```
import os
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient

TENANT_ID = "xxxx"
CLIENT_ID = "xxxx"
KEY = "xxxx"

credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
        client_id = CLIENT_ID,
        secret = KEY,
        tenant = TENANT_ID
        )

subscription_id = "xxxx"

client = ResourceManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)

resource_group_params = {'location': 'eastus'}
resource_group = client.resource_groups.create_or_update('groupName', resource_group_params)

print resource_group
```

You can more details from [ResourceGroupsOperations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-resource/azure.mgmt.resource.resources.v2018_05_01.operations.resourcegroupsoperations?view=azure-python). Good Luck!